# How to specify an arbitrary template argument for a function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I wasn't sure how to articulate what I'm asking so hopefully some code will make it clear. I'm trying to create my own matrix math library for my game engine rather than using an existing one such as glm (a learning experience). I bit of code for reference:

```
template<size_t S1, size_t S2> struct matrix: std::array<std::array<float, S2>, S1>
{
    matrix()
    {
        *this = 0;
    }

    matrix<S1, S2>& operator=(const float& value)
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < S1; ++i)
        {
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < S2; ++j)
            {
                this[i][j] = value;
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // other operator overloads
};

struct vec2: matrix<1, 2>
{
    float& x()
    {
        return this->_M_elems[0][0];
    }

    float& y()
    {
        return this->_M_elems[0][1];
    }
};

struct vec3: matrix<1, 3>
{
    float& x()
    {
        return this->_M_elems[0][0];
    }
    float& y()
    {
        return this->_M_elems[0][1];
    }
    float& z()
    {
        return this->_M_elems[0][2];
    }
};
```

I'm trying to overload the multiplication operation (`operator*`) for my matrix struct so that when I try to multiple two matrices it performs the dot product of the two. A couple rules for performing the dot product on matrices are:

> The number of columns of the 1st matrix must equal the number of rows of the 2nd matrix.

and

> The result will have the same number of rows as the 1st matrix, and the same number of columns as the 2nd matrix.

And so I tried:

```
template<size_t S1, size_t S2> struct matrix: std::array<std::array<float, S2>, S1>
{
    matrix()
    {
        *this = 0;
    }

    matrix<S1, S2>& operator=(const float& value)
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < S1; ++i)
        {
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < S2; ++j)
            {
                this[i][j] = value;
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // other operator overloads

    matrix<S1, S3> operator*(const matrix<S2, S3>& multiplier)
    {
        matrix<S1, S3> dot_product;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < S1; ++i)
        {
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < S2; ++j)
            {
                for (uint32_t k = 0; k < S3; ++k)
                {
                    dot_product[i][k] += (this[i][j] * multiplier[j][k]);
                }
            }
        }

        return dot_product;
    }
}
```

And I'm not even sure if that is the correct way to perform the dot product since it fails to compile with S3 not being defined anywhere. My question is, how should I pass as a function parameter `matrix<S2, S3>` where S2 is already defined within the struct and S3 is an unknown size?

Edit: Thanks to the generous help I was able to get my code to work, for a test case:

```
matrix<2, 3> test1;
matrix<3, 2> test2;

test1[0][0] = 1;
test1[0][1] = 2;
test1[0][2] = 3;
test1[1][0] = 4;
test1[1][1] = 5;
test1[1][2] = 6;
test2[0][0] = 6;
test2[0][1] = 5;
test2[1][0] = 4;
test2[1][1] = 3;
test2[2][0] = 2;
test2[2][1] = 1;

auto result = test1 * test2;

std::cout << test1 << std::endl;
std::cout << test2 << std::endl;
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

prints to the console:

```
[ 1 2 3 ] 
[ 4 5 6 ]

[ 6 5 ] 
[ 4 3 ] 
[ 2 1 ]

[ 20 14 ] 
[ 56 41 ]
```

Which I verified [here.](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1311593076) I was only able to print the output to the console because of some other code not shown here (for posterity sake)

Comment: @Amadeus apologies, thats just what happened when I pasted out of my ide

Comment: you have to make the operator* a template function too, like so: `template <size_t S3> matrix<S1, S3> operator*(const matrix<S2,S3>& multiplier)...`

Comment: @linuxfever I swear I could've sworn I tried that and it threw a compiler error but it definitely works now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<size_t S3>
matrix<S1, S3> operator*(const matrix<S2, S3>& multiplier)
```

Also your `matrix<S1, S2>& operator=(const float& value)` is wrong.  The matrix corresponding to a float is generally a diagonal one.

Comment: For posterity sake could you change `class S3` to `size_t S3`> And thank you by the way

Comment: not sure what your comment means? my code works as intended, see my edit

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now. Yes that's not correct but I hasdn't even thought that far, I only threw that overload together so that I could zero the matrix upon creation, but thank you for pointing that out.